# Не понимаю как реализовать проверку на нахождение ID в файле JSON

Tags: python, json, discord, disnake

Имеется вот такой код:

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import ujson

def load_database():
    with open('DB.json', 'r') as file:
        return ujson.load(file)

def save_database(data):
    with open('DB.json', 'w') as file:
        ujson.dump(data, file, indent=4, escape_forward_slashes=False)

@bot.slash_command(name="register", description="Регистрирует участника для использования игр")
async def register(inter: disnake.AppCmdInter):
    username = str(inter.author.name)
    userID = str(inter.author.id)

    data = load_database()
    for player in range(len(data["players"])):
        if userID != data["players"][player]["id"]:
            data["players"].append({"id": userID, "name": username, "balance": 1000})
            save_database(data)
            await inter.send("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await inter.send("Вы были зарегестрированы ранее!", ephemeral=True)
```

И база данных в виде файла JSON:

```json
{
    "players": [
        {
            "id": "1234567890",
            "name": "ivan",
            "balance": 1000
        },
        {
            "id": "0987654321",
            "name": "vasya",
            "balance": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

При вводе команды бот пишет: *Вы были зарегестрированы ранее!* и сразу после *Вы успешно зарегистрированы!*

Как можно реализовать систему проверки на нахождение в базе данных?

P.s: сижу уже несколько часов и до сих пор не вдупляю =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если следовать логике: вы проходите циклом по всем игрокам в базе данных, и при проверке ваш бот отправляет сообщение для *каждого* пользователя из бд, а не только для текущего. Попробуйте это:

```py
...
ids = [data["players"][player]["id"] for player in range(len(data["players"]))]

if userID in ids:
    await inter.send("Вы были зарегестрированы ранее!", ephemeral=True)
else:
    data["players"].append({"id": userID, "name": username, "balance": 1000})
    save_database(data)
    await inter.send("Вы успешно зарегистрированы!", ephemeral=True)
```

**UPD:** прошу прощения, предыдущая версия кода все еще не решала проблему. Обновил и проверил, сейчас все должно быть в порядке